# TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types in tensorflow_addons RSquare

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

I'm creating a small regression model for a network with one hidden layer and this error just appeared and I can't get rid of it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.layers import Dense,Input
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

lossfunc=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001)
In=keras.Input(shape=(73,))
x=Dense(64,activation='relu')(In)
out=Dense(1,activation='linear')(x)
onelayer=keras.Model(inputs=In,outputs=out)

onelayer.compile(loss=lossfunc,optimizer=optimizer,metrics=tfa.metrics.RSquare())

onelayer.summary()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-aba7181b155c> in <module>
      9 out=Dense(1,activation='linear')(x)
     10 onelayer=keras.Model(inputs=In,outputs=out)
---> 11 onelayer.compile(loss=lossfunc,optimizer=optimizer,metrics=tfa.metrics.RSquare())
     12 onelayer.summary()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/typeguard/_checkers.py in check_type_internal(value, annotation, memo)
    668             return
    669 
--> 670     if not isinstance(value, origin_type):
    671         raise TypeCheckError(f"is not an instance of {qualified_name(origin_type)}")
    672 

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

I'm using google colab.

I tried the code in  R2score [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/RSquare), and I still get this error:

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import numpy as np

y_true = np.array([1, 4, 3], dtype=np.float32)
y_pred = np.array([2, 4, 4], dtype=np.float32)
metric = tfa.metrics.r_square.RSquare()
metric.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
result = metric.result()
result.numpy()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-109e77a0c3d1> in <module>
      1 y_true = np.array([1, 4, 3], dtype=np.float32)
      2 y_pred = np.array([2, 4, 4], dtype=np.float32)
----> 3 metric = tfa.metrics.r_square.RSquare()
      4 metric.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
      5 result = metric.result()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/typeguard/_checkers.py in check_type_internal(value, annotation, memo)
    668             return
    669 
--> 670     if not isinstance(value, origin_type):
    671         raise TypeCheckError(f"is not an instance of {qualified_name(origin_type)}")
    672 

TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

I have no access to isinstance() how can I fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use
pip install typeguard==2.13.3

typeguard 3.0.0 version was released recently that's the reason why it's not working

Comment: Version 2.13.0 works fine, too. If you are in a conda environment, you can use `conda install -c esri typeguard` (https://anaconda.org/esri/typeguard)